# How to interpret CURL headers sent by user

Tags: php, apache, unix, curl

I am creating an API using Laravel and Apache as the backend. My predicament is this, when I type a curl command in my terminal like,

```
curl -H "API KEY: NIKAPIKEY" --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:8888/awesome-calendar/public/config
```

How do I read the header API KEY in my php backend? Like I can read the POST parameters as $_REQUEST.

Comment: short answer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Comment: Any HTTP-Header is available in the superglobal `$_SERVER` and starts with `HTTP_`, as long as the webserver passes them to PHP and Apache is fast with throwing away invalid Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @nogad

The function **apache_request_headers** acts like the var_dump for all HTTP headers

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php